# Cannot merge binary files during merging feature to Master branch

Tags: git, merge

I am new to git stuff, I need help to fix this issue.

I am getting below merge issue.

```
C:\work\Automation Learning\Automation-testing-practise>git merge dev_indianGuy
warning: Cannot merge binary files: target/classes/com/kits/sit/Base_Setup/Base_Setup.class (HEAD vs. dev_indianGuy)
Auto-merging target/classes/com/kits/sit/Base_Setup/Base_Setup.class
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in target/classes/com/kits/sit/Base_Setup/Base_Setup.class
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

C:\work\Automation Learning\Automation-testing-practise>git push origin master
Everything up-to-date

C:\work\Automation Learning\Automation-testing-practise>git checkout dev_indianGuy
error: you need to resolve your current index first
target/classes/com/kits/sit/Base_Setup/Base_Setup.class: needs merge

C:\work\Automation Learning\Automation-testing-practise>git checkout
```

My git repo link: https://github.com/dib1987/Automation-testing-practise

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file in your working copy is still the copy from your current branch – in other words, it was not modified by the merge attempt. To resolve the conflict and keep this file:

```
 git add Base_Setup.class
 git commit –m “My commit message for the merge”
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works .so what i did , 
C:\work\Automation Learning\Automation-testing-practise>git add target/classes/com/kits/sit/Base_Setup/Base_Setup.class
->git commit -m "changes made merge issue by indian guy"
->git merge dev_indianGuy
Already up to date.
->git branch dev_indianGuy
* master
->git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
->git push origin master

Comment: If it worked then can you please upvote this answer!